# Looking for a desktop mail client that works with Office 365

Tags: email-client, office365

I have used Outlook 2003, 2007, 2010 and 2012 with Office 365, however I was looking for a free solution to place on several netbooks that do not require anything more than a standard email client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned only with email (I can't imagine you'd want to use Office 365 with OpenOffice or something) then [according to Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/online/help/en-us/helphowto/0f842320-7a88-46b5-ae36-94ba880d8525.htm), any client that supports POP3 should work just fine:

> Microsoft Exchange Online now supports the POP3 protocol, so you can send and receive Exchange Online e-mail using any POP3 e-mail client.

You will have to contact support and have POP3 enabled per account however:

> If you are a Microsoft Online Services administrator, you can contact Microsoft Online Services Technical Support to request POP3 service.

It's also worth noting that there is a [Kiosk Worker plan](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/all-plans.aspx) available as well that providers web based email. You may want to look in to this as an alternative solution.

<s>Keep in mind that POP3 is not available on these plans.</s>

#### Update:

I'm not sure if you can access this plan through POP or not. The plans page states the following:

> ...as well as POP email access with Exchange Online

However the `Online Services Help and How To` page states:

> Additionally, POP3 e-mail access cannot be enabled for Microsoft Online Services Deskless SKU accounts.

I hopped in a chat with a Microsoft sales rep but got no answer out of them. The chat transcript is [mildly amusing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7604224#7604224).